# Динамические данные в статический файл?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

1. Что использую: Node.js с фреймворком Express.js. Статический main.js файл, который будет отправляться клиенту в браузер. В этом файле лежит код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let allVideo = new window.VPlayer('127.0.0.1');
  /**
   * function (number, port, canvas_element, container)
   */
  allVideo.addVideo(0, 49002, $("#video-canvas-1").get(0), $('#jsmpeg1'));
  allVideo.addVideo(1, 49004, $("#video-canvas-2").get(0), $('#jsmpeg2'));
  allVideo.addVideo(2, 49006, $("#video-canvas-3").get(0), $('#jsmpeg3'));
  allVideo.addVideo(3, 49008, $("#video-canvas-4").get(0), $('#jsmpeg4'));
});
```

Вся загвоздка находиться в двух местах, в единственном параметре для VPlayer и параметре порт. Хотелось бы, чтобы эти данные прописывались не жестко в файле, а брались из конфиг файла, дабы улучшить мобильность приложения.

Этот файл(main.js) является публичным, и находиться в директории, относително корня приложения в **public/js/main.js**. Соответственно в Express.js и прописано, что это является директорией ресурсов.

Была идея сделать это при помощи Grunt(на данный момент используется он), или перебежать на Gulp.

Если это возможно, посоветуйте как это можно сделать.

p.s. Ip и порт нужны для указания конечной точки для WebSocket'a. Приложение открывает WebSocket и шлет по нему чанки информации в браузер клиента, декодируются, и выводяться в Canvas(видео поток).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs')
let main  = fs.readFileSync('./main.js', 'utf-8');
main.replace(/127.0.0.1/, 3000);
fs.writeFile('./main.js', main, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Файл main.js перезаписан");
  });
```

Как-то так

Comment: Хм. Хорошая идея. Не совсем то, что требовалось, но на первое время и так сойдет. Спасибо